# Actual Sizes of An Image loaded with a Path

Tags: unity, unityscript, image

I have a method which selects an Image from device. I need to show this image to users.

The codes below works fine, does what I need.

```
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(512, 512);
    texture.LoadImage(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath));
    texture.Compress(false);
    texture.Apply();
```

I just want to know how to change `new Texture2D(512, 512)` to real size of this Image.

Maybe this: `new Texture2D(img.ActualWidth, img.ActualHeight)`

Any idea?

Additionly is there any way to get original width and height from an Image loaded from a `base64String` ?

```
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);
    Texture2D textureImage= new Texture2D(**250, 300**);
    textureImage.LoadImage(imageBytes);
```

Comment: Is it important to have the image size there? When you use LoadImage it resizes the texture for you. It could just as easily be (2,2)

Comment: Also note that you don’t need to explicitly call compress or apply if you create the texture with the dxt format to begin with

Comment: @EdMarty I didn't know LoadImage() resize the texture. Thank you! Please post this as an answer so that I can choose as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use LoadImage it resizes the texture for you. It could just as easily be `new Texture2D(2,2)`.

Also note that you don’t need to explicitly call compress or apply if you create the texture with the dxt format to begin with:

```
//Use DXT5 for images which may have an alpha channel, or DXT1 for images that do not have one:
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.DXT5);
texture.LoadImage(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath));
//No need to call compress or apply here
```